# Topology of a convergent sequence of stable maps on a symplectic manifold

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, gromov-witten-theory, pseudo-holomorphic-curves

Let $(M,\omega)$ be a compact symplectic manifold. Let $J$ be a compatible almost complex structure. Let $g$ be the Riemannian metric corresponding to $\omega,J$.

Let $f_\nu\colon C_\nu\to M$ be a sequence of $J$-holomorphic curves where $C_\nu$ are smooth closed Riemann surfaces and $f_\nu$ are injective.
Assume that this sequence converges to a stable map $f\colon C\to M$ which will be assumed to be injective too, but $C$ is a nodal curve which does not have to be smooth.

Let us fix a point $p\in f(C)$.

**Question.** Is it true that there exists $\varepsilon_0>0$ such that for any $\varepsilon\in (0,\varepsilon_0)$
and any $\nu>\nu_0(\varepsilon)$
the intersection
$$B(p,\varepsilon)\cap f_\nu(C_\nu),$$
where $B(p,\varepsilon)$ is the $\varepsilon$-ball centered at $p$ with respect to the metric $g$, is contractible if $p$ is the image of a smooth point of $C$, and is homotopically equivalent to the circle if $p$
is the image of a node of $C$?